# rails 3 how to associate a new object without mass-assign error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, mass-assignment

I came back to the relatively "old book" Head First rails, which was published for Rails 2.3.
Now, going back again through those samples and using Rails 3 I came up with some questions.

Let's say that I'm adapting the sample for coconut airways and instead of flights and seats, I have a project and tasks.

The page shows a project description and below a list of tasks associated to that project. so far so good. now below that there is a form to create new task. This task needs a Task object and the project_id. here is when things do not work as before.

if you want to do it like the old style you will type:

```
<%= render :partial => "new_task", 
    :locals =>  {:task => Task.new(@project.id)} %>
```

well, this is showing the mass-assign error.

Then I tried to pass both as parameter:

```
<%= render :partial => "new_task", 
    :locals =>  {:task => Task.new, :project_id  => @project.id} %>
```

and assign it in the partial

```
<%= f.hidden_field :project_id, :value => project_id %>
```

any hint?

EDITED:

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  attr_accessible :title
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  attr_accessible :description, :title
end

Comment: What does your model attr_accessible look like?

Comment: I just added those mode. shall I add access to project_id in task?

Comment: this seems to work, if you put this as answer I'll mark it as correct. thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad that fixed it!  I'll add it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your model's attr_accessible you can include these assignments to be made.  For more information about attr_accessible and mass assignment see: [Ruby on Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html#method-i-attr_accessible)